# Multiple objects in pickle file

Tags: python, pickle

I want to be able to add multiple objects to pickle file and be able to retrieve it later. I got to the point where I can save objects but when I loading a file, only last entry is loaded. What is my mistake?

```
import pickle

class People():
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, mobile_no, home_no):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.mobile_no = mobile_no
        self.home_no = home_no

    def DisplayContacts(self):
        print("First Name: \t", self.name)
        print("Surname: \t", self.surname)
        print("Age: \t", self.age)
        print("Mobile Number: \t", self.mobile_no)
        print("Home Number: \t", self.home_no)
        print()


def addContact():
    newname = str(input("First name: \t"))
    newsurname = str(input("Surname: \t"))
    newage = int(input("Age: \t"))
    newmobile_no = int(input("Mobile Number: \t"))
    newhome_no = int(input("Home Number: \t"))
    newContact = People(newname, newsurname, newage, newmobile_no, newhome_no) 
    return newContact

cont = 1

contacts = []


while cont == 1:
    user = input("Do you want to add contact? (Y/N)")
    if user == "Y" or user == "y":
        print ("works")
        contacts.append(addContact())
        file = open("List.pickle", "wb")
        pickle.dump(contacts, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        file.close()
    else:
        print ("111")
        cont = 0

useropen = input("open file? (Y/N)")
if useropen == "Y" or useropen == "y":
    with open ("List.pickle", "rb") as pickled_file:
        contacts = pickle.load(pickled_file)
else:
    print("Null")
```

Now it seems like it file is empty when I'm trying to load it:

```
import pickle

class People():
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, mobile_no, home_no):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.mobile_no = mobile_no
        self.home_no = home_no

    def DisplayContacts(self):
        print("First Name: \t", self.name)
        print("Surname: \t", self.surname)
        print("Age: \t", self.age)
        print("Mobile Number: \t", self.mobile_no)
        print("Home Number: \t", self.home_no)
        print()


def addContact():
    newname = str(input("First name: \t"))
    newsurname = str(input("Surname: \t"))
    newage = int(input("Age: \t"))
    newmobile_no = int(input("Mobile Number: \t"))
    newhome_no = int(input("Home Number: \t"))
    newContact = People(newname, newsurname, newage, newmobile_no, newhome_no) 
    return newContact

cont = 1

contacts = []


while cont == 1:
    user = input("Do you want to add contact? (Y/N)")
    if user == "Y" or user == "y":
        print ("works")
        contacts.append(addContact())
        file = open("CList.pickle", "ab")
        pickle.dump(contacts, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        file.close()
    else:
        print ("111")
        cont = 0

useropen = input("open file? (Y/N)")
if useropen == "Y" or useropen == "y":

    with open ("CList.pickle", "rb") as pickled_file:
        contacts = pickle.load(pickled_file)
else:
    print("Null")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening your pickle file with mode `wb`, which truncates (set's the file back to empty before writing anything new).  The mode you want is `a` which opens for appending.

Comment: I have changed "wb" to "ab" and now nothing is loading up, what could it be?

Answer (score 4):

You are truncating your Pickle file at every iteration of the `while` loop, since you are opening it in `"wb"` mode.

Since you are continuously adding contacts to the `contacts` list during the loop (and then dumping a separate copy of this list with one more contact on each iteration -- probably not what you intend), I would simply take the whole pickle dumping part of your code and move it just after the `while` loop, dumping the full contacts list once -- no need for multiple objects.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @Ethan Furman says, there seems to be a difference in the functionality of `'b'` in windows and unix ([reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)). Your code might work well on unix but would truncate on windows os